# Is palmrest harmful for macbook pro 15 retina?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, macbook-pro

I recently got a new Macbook Pro 15 retina. I already have a keyboard cover on it, and earlier today I put a palmrest and trackpad cover on it as well.

However, [This Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4384) website says that applying palmrests and keyboard covers might actually be harmful to the screen and display. On the other hand, interestingly though, [this Apple sales](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TW022LL/A/moshi-15-palmguard-palm-rest-protector-for-macbook-pro) website  itself lists Moshi Palmrest as one of its supported Mac accessories.

I'm thinking applying the palmrest will not do any damage as such? Please help!

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Any palmrest has a chance that it will be in contact with the screen, when the laptop's lid is closed.

Having anything in contact with the screen raises the risk that the screen may become damaged - at least on the surface of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the small print

<sub>Important: Information about products not manufactured by Apple is provided for information purposes only and does not constitute Apple’s recommendation or endorsement. Please contact the vendor for additional information.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Just a question- how did you manage to write the disclaimer in a smaller font size? Throughout my time in Stack Exchange, I never found a way to do that.

Comment: <sub>If you click Edit it will show you how I did it</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the rubber seal on the bezel around the screen of the MBP lid? It looks from your link that the Moshi palm rest has a constant thickness and covers also the area which is contacted by this seal when the lid closes, so the relative distance between screen and palm rest area is maintained.

I guess Apple's warning is for palm rests which are higher in the middle and will touch the screen when the lid is closed. And to make the lawyers happy who want to avoid users with scratched or cracked screens suing.

As for the sensibility of using special palm rests - this should be a question of its own.